# ASIHTTPRequest not waiting for streamed response

Tags: php, iphone, ios, stream, asihttprequest

I'm using the great ASIHTTPRequest library on iOS, I created my request as follows:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl/myscript.php"]];
[request addPostValue:@"myvalue" forKey:@"mykey"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
[request setTimeOutSeconds:30];
[request setShouldAttemptPersistentConnection:YES];
[request setDidReceiveDataSelector:@selector(request:didReceiveData:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

Now as you probably see I'm trying to handle the response as it's coming in, in fact I wan't to keep a UITableView up to date. So my important part of the script looks like follows:

```
while(....){.....looping;   echo $myvar; }
```

But my iPhone refuses to wait for the full response, the request terminates after first chunk of data was recieved. Any suggestions where the problem is caused and how to fix?

Comment: Does your requestFailed: method get called? If so what's the error?

Comment: No, the request is able to finish itself very well, expect a little wo well because it terminates too early and doesn't wait for additional streamed content coming from my script

Comment: Have you checked in (say) a web browser, and verified if the full response is delivered in that case?

Comment: I can't really check via browser but did using the shell, there everything seems to work fine, in fact I added a sleep(1); at the end of every while-iteration to really be sure that there is an outgoing iteration and output serverside

Comment: If you remove your request:didReceiveData:, does request.responseString in requestFinished: contain the full data? If not I think you should possibly try and capture in wireshark or charlesproxy too, see what they make of the data.